# How do I use an impl function in the main function in rust?

Tags: rust

I want to use a function in the main function in a rust program that I am building to help me learn rust and come up with an error: `self` value is a keyword only available in methods with a `self` parameterrustc(E0424). What can I fix in my code so that this error does not happen?

```
pub use crate::user_account::user_account;
use rand::Rng;

#[allow(dead_code)]
pub trait UserInfo {
    fn user_info(&mut self);
    fn acc_no(&mut self);
    fn yes(self);
    fn bank_new_user(self);
}
pub struct NewUser {
    age: String,
    new_user: String,
    account: String,
    account_number: i32,
    routing_number: i32,
    select: String,
}
impl UserInfo for NewUser {
    fn user_info(&mut self) {
        self.age = String::new();
        self.new_user = String::new();
        println!("What is your name?");
        print!("Name: ");
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut self.new_user);
        println!(" ");
        println!("Hello {}, What is your age? ", self.new_user);
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut self.age);
        let age2: String = self.age.trim().into();

    }

    fn acc_no(&mut self) {
        println!(
            "We will generate a new account number \
               and routing number for you."
        );
        self.account_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(10000000..99999999);
        println!("Your account number is {}", self.account_number);
        self.routing_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(10000000..99999999);
        println!("Your account routing number is {}", self.routing_number);
    }
    fn yes(self) {
        NewUser::user_info(&mut self);
        NewUser::acc_no(&mut self);
    }
    //function I want to use in main.
    fn bank_new_user(self) {
        self.account = String::new();
        println!("Would you like to make a new account with us today?");
        loop {
            println!(
                " yes: continue to application, no: continue browsing , \
        or exit: to exit"
            );
            self.account.clear();
            std::io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut self.account)
                .expect("please type yes, no or exit.");
            let account = self.account.trim();
            match account {
                "yes" => {
                    self.yes();
                    break;
                }

                "no" => {
                    println!("You do not need an account to continue browsing.");
                    println!("Have a wonderful day and thank you for considering Mars Banking!");
                    break;
                }
                "exit" => {
                    println!(
                        "Thank you for choosing Mars Banking for your banking needs!\
                Have a wonderful day!"
                    );
                    break;
                }
                _ => {
                    println!("Error! Enter yes, no, or exit.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

pub mod new_user;
mod settings;
mod user_account;
pub use crate::settings::settings;
pub use crate::user_account::user_account;
use new_user::NewUser;
use new_user::UserInfo;

fn main() {
    loop{
        let mut select = String::new();
            println!("Welcome to Mars Banking!");
            println!("What would you like to do today?");
            println!("Create a new account: 1\nLogin: 2\nSettings: 3\nExit: 4");
            select.clear();
            std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut select);
            let select = select.trim();
            match select {
                //Here is where the error happens.
                "1" => NewUser::bank_new_user(self),
                "2" => user_account(),
                "3" => settings(),
                "4" => break,
                _ => {}
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conventional pattern for this sort of constructor is a static method that doesn't take a `self` argument, like this:

```rust
impl NewUser {
    fn bank_new_user() {
        let mut new_user = NewUser { /* initialize the fields */ };
        // Edit or use new_user as necessary
    }
}
```

you can see an example of this [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/methods.html), in the methods defined for `Point`:

```rust
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

// Implementation block, all `Point` associated functions & methods go in here
impl Point {
    // This is an "associated function" because this function is associated with
    // a particular type, that is, Point.
    //
    // Associated functions don't need to be called with an instance.
    // These functions are generally used like constructors.
    fn origin() -> Point {
        Point { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 }
    }

    // Another associated function, taking two arguments:
    fn new(x: f64, y: f64) -> Point {
        Point { x: x, y: y }
    }
}
```

notice how niether `origin` nor `new` take `self` as an argument.

Comment: Thank you it got rid of the error and gave me a better understanding of what's going on with the type safety.